# Linux program argument with vs without space

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

I saw some cases where there is no space between the parameter and the parameter value of a specific command, for example:

```
mysql -u [user] -p[pass] mydb < mydb.sq
```

> NOTE: there's no space between -p & [pass]

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110023/6348859

Why is there no space needed in this case? Is it always possible to omit the space with any command before specifying the value, or is it even necessary in some cases, and what determines it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'mysql' tool uses the common *getopt_long()* function to parse its command-line arguments (or at least emulates its behavior closely enough).

In both getopt() and getopt_long(), the space is never required – if the option is defined as taking an argument, you can always just stick the value right next to the option. (Though, keep in mind that not all programs use getopt in the first place!)

However, the difference is in whether the argument is required vs optional:

`-u` is defined as taking a *required argument*, so both `-u Fred` and `-uFred` are acceptable, and the same goes for long options where either `--user Fred` or `--user=Fred` is okay.

`-p` is defined as taking an *optional argument*, so `-pFoobar` is always acceptable but `-p Foobar` may be ambiguous (the next word could be either the option argument or a positional argument); in that case the parser will assume that the option was specified *without* any argument.

(The reason that -p is defined as taking an optional argument, instead of it being required like with -u, is that command-line arguments may be visible to other users and even stored in system logs, so the tool would rather read the password through an interactive prompt.)

As an extended example of getopt(), in one program `-abcdef` could be parsed into six options with no arguments, but in another it could be parsed into options -a -b with no arguments then option -c with the argument "def", and in yet another it could be parsed into option -a with argument "bcdef".

> Why is there no space needed in this case? Is it always possible to omit the space with any command before specifying the value, or is it even necessary in some cases, and what determines it?

You have it the wrong way around: the space was never needed in the other case, either. Instead, in this case, the space *must not* be present -p while it was allowed with -u.

This doesn't apply to *all* commands, however. Not all C programs use getopt_long(), most non-C programs do not use it at all (e.g. Python's ArgumentParser is of course written in Python, though it still behaves almost like getopt_long).

There are some which are *mostly* getopt-like but just different enough to be annoying (for example, curl does not accept the '=' after long options, it always needs a space), and there are many which don't follow the getopt style at all. (For example, many Golang programs using its standard argument parsing package use the "MIT/X11" option style.)

Comment: How is " -p Foobar" ambiguous? If the program identifies the "-p" argument it reads the next argument as its value, not so?

Comment: You missed the part about the argument being _optional_ -- specifying just `-p` with no argument would mean "password is required, but prompt for it interactively". So when you run `mysql -p Foobar`, there are two possibilities: [-p with no argument + "Foobar" as database name] or [-p with "Foobar" argument + no database name]. A greedy parser would always choose the latter and would make it impossible to specify the former.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely program-specific. `mysql`'s `-p` behavior is rather unusual, but justified and not unheard of.

In case of `mysql`, the `-p` alone triggers a slightly different behavior: the program will ask for password interactively, rather than use the one provided as an argument to `-p`. If the space between `-p` and the password was allowed, `mysql` wouldn't know if you're trying to provide the password or if it's just another argument. Disallowing the space removes any ambiguity.

So in case of `mysql` the string `-pfoo` is interpreted as `-p` with an argument `foo`. Most programs would interpret it as equivalent to `-p -f -o -o` (four separate switches, with `-o` repeated).

Another notable example is `sed`'s `-i` switch, which also works both with and without an argument.

Comment: It is not MySQL-specifc at all -- that's just the standard behavior of "optional arguments" in GNU getopt_long(). In fact even in standard Unix getopt() (which only supports required but not optional arguments), if 'p' is defined to take an argument then both `-p foo` *and* `-pfoo` will be interpreted in the same way (option 'p' with argument 'foo').

Comment: So mysql basically sees it as "-pfoo" and checks if it starts with "-p" to determine if it's the password parameter?

Comment: @sermonionx Exactly.